# How to stop ads redirecting to Google Play store?

Tags: google-play-store, ads

I have a similar problem to
[How can I stop being redirected to the App Store/Google Store by dodgy ad-scripts?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/how-can-i-stop-being-redirected-to-the-app-store-google-store-by-dodgy-ad-script)
however the solution provided there doesn't work:

I'm opening in-app ads on purpose for in-app rewards (freemium game), and some of them open the Play store after they finish playing. I want to continue seeing these ads, so I can't just block them, and redirecting to a web browser changes virtually nothing on the problem. Can I prevent those ads from sending me to the store?

I'm using an older Samsung Android, 4.4.4 according to the device.

I think a redirect tag would fit this question as well, but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up installing Firefox to use as my web browser and my problem was solved.

The phone started asking which app to open the links in instead of opening the store directly.

Comment: Hi, while this might be a solution, I'm trying to understand the reasoning. The question is talking about in-app ads, not ads on websites. In-app ads are using web view/native component and it is possible to redirect to Play Store directly, skipping the browser entirely.

Comment: @AndrewT. While you're not wrong the solution proposed is in fact similar to what ultimately ended up happening for me, at some point the phone started asking which app to open the links in instead of opening the store directly. Either way, I have since switched devices and stopped experiencing the issue.

Comment: @MrRedstoner I see, thanks, looks like it's either "have multiple apps that handle specific links to prompt the user" and/or "reset the default app for handling Play Store links".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for Android:

1. Turn on the Pin windows feature. (For my phone, it's located in Settings --> Lock screen and security --> Other security settings --> Pin windows.)
2. When you're about to watch an ad for rewards, pin the app window.
3. Once the ad ends, it'll try to redirect to google store and fail. Then, you hit the back button, and voila: there's your in-app reward.